# dividing the panels using flex

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I am new to css and flex. Below is the working url in stackblitz.

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bh8m8u?file=src/app/app.component.html
```

I have  a left panel and main panel and a click button on the top of the page.

Requirement 1 On the click of the button i want to open the side panel. For some reason the side panel is not opening.

Requirement 2. I want to update the css to use flex if is possible because i am new to flex also

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your sidePanelOpen variable isn't updating, and your sidePanel element is translated -150%, so it's off to the left of the screen

Never done any Angular but using the power of logic I've figured out half your answer. Now all you need to do is read a quick CSS tutorial

You originally were just setting this variable true. Using ! you can negate the sidePanelOpen value and get a toggle action going
.ts

```
openSideBar() {
    this.sidePanelOpen = !this.sidePanelOpen;
    console.log(this.sidePanelOpen);
}
```

Here you had the toggled class being set on the wrong element.
.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{'toggled' : sidePanelOpen}" class="sidebar" id="sidePanel">
  <div>
    <span id='close'>x</span>
    <h4>Bangalore </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, the toggled class won't do anything unless you have some css to hide your side panel
.css

```
#sidePanel.toggled {
  display: none;
}
```